# Is A Class Library The Correct Project To Use To Store Images As Resources To Be Used By A WPF Project

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, resources

I have loaded a few .jpg files into a class library project under Visual Studio 2015 and set them to build as resource and copy when new. It appears to work fine when I use it with my WPF project.  Is there another way to store images into a DLL or is this method correct?

======================================

Update 3/22/2016 5:02 pm

Just for some clarity, I am adding the ImageSource statement to my App.xaml file as Application.Resources section as follows:

```
<ImageSource x:Key="OkImage">pack://application:,,,/MyStyles;component/ok.png</ImageSource>
```

Then I reference the OkImage keyword in my WPF window xaml as follows for an image control:

```
<Image x:Name="image" Source="{DynamicResource OkImage}" 
               Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="66,25,0,0" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
```

This is how I am pulling the image out of the .DLL and into the WPF file. The purpose for the .DLL with the images is to share it with others to use the same images on their controls for the current and future projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is A Class Library The Correct Project To Use To Store Images As Resources To Be Used By A WPF Project

Absolutely!  WPF refers to this as *resource files* - files that are marked as **Build Action** of **Resource**.  Such resources are then compiled into the assembly where they can be loaded from c# code or via XAML via [Pack URIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx).  This is why WPF apps should not use WinForms style **.resx** files because XAML are generally unable to utilise them.

- You use resource files when the resources are known at compile time or when you don't need to update them after building or deploying.
- Resource files cut down on the number of files to distribute

MSDN:

> If an application data file must always be available to an application, the only way to guarantee availability is to compile it into an application's main executable assembly or one of its referenced assemblies. This type of application data file is known as a resource file. - [Tell me more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970494(v=vs.100).aspx)

OP:

> I have loaded a few .jpg files into a class library project under Visual Studio 2015 and set them to build as resource and copy when new

When marking files as **Resource** don't, don't mark them as *"copy when new"*.  That defeats the purpose of resource files.  You're merely copying an additional image file that most likely isn't used.  Resource files should be embedded in the assembly.

OP:

> Is there another way to store images into a DLL or is this method correct?

You can also use **Content files**.  This technique is useful when files are likely to be changed after the fact but you don't want to recompile your application.  Your application has a link to the dependent resource that it evaluates at runtime.  [Tell me more about content files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970494(v=vs.100).aspx)

**Site of Origin Files**
I must admit I don't know much about this having just read about it.  It appears to be useful when resources are not known at build time; useful for partial trust applications where access is limited.  Full trust applications may find the SoOF syntax more useful over the `file://` which generally requires the full path.

MSDN has this to say of SoOF:

> ...there are times when you may want to establish either an implicit or non-existent relationship between an assembly and an application data file, including when:
>
> - A file doesn't exist when at compile time.
> - You don't know what files your assembly will require until run time.
> - You want to be able to update files without recompiling the assembly that they are associated with.
> - Your application uses large data files, such as audio and video, and you only want users to download them if they choose to.

[Tell me more about SoOF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970494(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: thanks for the info.  Good catch on the  "Copy if Newer" property value. I'm guessing the "Copy to Output Directory" drop down property should be set to "Do not Copy" so the images stay in the DLL?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a resource file (or multiple resource files) to store this data. Make a new folder in a project and call it Resources (name doesn't really matter). Then right click the new folder and click add -> new item -> and select "Resource file" (see image #1). Name it something & then you should have a something.resx file in your new folder (see image #2). Then open the newly created resource file & you can see that you have the option in the upper left hand corner of the editor to add existing files (browse your file system for files) to the resx file. Once you've added the files you can access them as image/string/audio/etc files in your source code using the namespace and class that was automatically created for them. I've included a code example below.

[image]

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Bitmap myUntitledImage = WpfApplication1.Resources.Resource1.Untitled; //Untitled is the name of my image
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Though a jolly good answer, convention for WPF apps is not to use the WinForms `.resx` way of loading resources but rather [Resource files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970494(v=vs.100).aspx) referenced via [Pack URIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx) where each resource is a separate file in the project compiled with a **Build Action** of **Resource**.

Comment: @MickyD I wasn't aware of that, but thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

The method is not wrong, but I think you need to consider a case that you might want to upgrade this DLL (either for one picture or more). If you store many pictures as resources in it, then the size of the DLL will increase and therefore, if you change on DLL, you need to redistribute a new DLL to all of your clients. If that's not your case, you can store your pictures in an external DLL.

About performance considerations, resources are cached in memory. Resources use a System.Resources.ResourceManager, and this does caching of the images as well as strings. So all of the images you store in your resource assembly will be stored in the memory. This is another point you need to consider.